# Excess whitespace in table in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I'm having a problem with excess whitespace in my table in Firefox.

Here is a live example: http://test.komak.nl/seals/cartridge-seals

This jsFiddle shows me the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DVbCC/

In Chrome or Safari, every row is neatly placed below the other with minimal whitespace, but in Firefox, all rows have excess whitespace on the bottom.
From what I've read, this happens more often in Firefox to images. Then `display:block;` is the solution. However, that won't work here with table cells.

If you inspect the table, you can see I added `margin:0; padding:0;` to the `<p>`'s and `padding-bottom:0;` to the `<td>`'s, but that obviously doesn't do the trick.
I've also played around with `display: block` and `float:left`  but that doesn't play nice with tables.

I'm hoping someone here can push me in the right direction?

P.s. I work on Mac OSX

Comment: looks exactly alike to me, which part of the design do you have too much space?

Comment: Firefox: http://tinypic.com/r/1r9nuq/5 and Chrome: http://tinypic.com/r/2058itl/5

Comment: I have just debugged your issue and there is a serious issues with the way you have formatted your table by adding colspans and rowspans. The inconsistencies are visible and I have removed the inconsistent TR's and checked and they are working perfectly fine. Here is the example of it. http://jsfiddle.net/DVbCC/1/ You need to rework on the format, or this will act like a patch and will have cumulative effects in future. - @Valk6

Comment: Ok, so removing the image on the right solves the issue, but I need it there. How should I place it, without going to a table-in-table construction?

Comment: Hmm I don't think my table formatting is wrong and my use of `rowspan` is legitimate. The one extra `<td>` holds the image on the right size. It is `colspan=2`, so it can stick out more inwards than the logo on top, without interfering with either the title or text.

Answer (score 2):

In case of such inconsistencies across browsers, I suggest you to use a CSS Reset probably [Eric Mayer Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

This will normalize all your discrepancies and shall render your page with uniform consistencies across all browsers.

**The Code:**

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried to fiddle around with line-height and added the CSS Reset, but the problem persists. But i will look into the table structure as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Different browsers have slightly different implementations for things like default padding, text size, etc. The easiest first step to take is to include a CSS Reset file (before any other CSS), which standardizes these across all browsers.

Some will provide 'standard' versions of each element styling (so headers all still resemble headers, but are now all the same default font, size, spacing across browsers), whilst others will strip literally everything of any styling rules whatsoever.

There's plenty available, a list of which are available here: http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: I tried Erik Mayer's CSS Reset, but it didn't solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding here:

```
.breadcrumb {
    color: #5D5D5D;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```